# How to fork a KDE widget from system dir in my home dir?

Tags: qml, kde-plasma

I have a KDE4 desktop on an enterprise server (CentOS 7) where I don't have root access. *Yes*, KDE **4** still.

I want to take the default [Pager](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Pager) widget (which displays the virtual desktops on the panel) and modify it so that it does not display the window outlines on the desktop indicators. It obscures the workspace name text.

I found this [old thread](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=140136) which attempts to do the same, but it was never resolved, and they were not restricted to non-root solutions as I am.

My attempt was to copy the widget files from the system directory into my home directory and make a new version with hacked QML (see changes at end).

But after restarting KDE, I do not see the new widget available to use when right clicking the panel and going through the *Add widget* dialog.

I cannot find much relevant documentation on KDE4 anymore. Does anyone remember what to do?

---

#### Forking the widget as org.kde.pager-nowinoutline

```sh
$ mkdir -p ~/.kde/share/apps/plasma/packages
$ cp -r /usr/share/kde4/apps/plasma/packages/org.kde.pager ~/.kde/share/apps/plasma/packages/org.kde.pager-nowinoutline
```

#### metadata.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Pager (No window outlines)
Icon=user-desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=Plasma/Applet
X-Plasma-MainScript=ui/main.qml
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Author=
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Email=
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name=org.kde.pager-nowinoutline
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Version=1.0
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Category=Windows and Tasks
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Depends=
X-KDE-PluginInfo-License=GPL
X-KDE-PluginInfo-EnabledByDefault=true
```

#### content/ui/main.qml

```
// ...

// Comment out this part responsible for drawing the window outlines
/*
                Repeater {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                    model: windows

                    Rectangle {
                        id: windowRect
                    // ...
                    }
                // ...
                }
*/

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by keeping the same widget name (in both the directory structure and `metadata.desktop`.

```
$ cp -r /usr/share/kde4/apps/plasma/packages/org.kde.pager ~/.kde/share/apps/plasma/packages
```

This is enough so that, when you restart KDE (or alternatively, remove and re-add the widget in the panel), your `$HOME` version will override the system version.

As for the QML, I couldn't just comment out all that as I did in the original question, as it broke some other functionality such that the widget wouldn't even load.

I ended up just adding

```
visible: false
```

within the context of

```
                Repeater {
                    model: windows

                    Rectangle {
                        id: windowRect
```

and that prevents the windows from being drawn.